# Eclipse: changes on project in workspace not making changes in the folder project was imported from

Tags: java, eclipse, git, atlassian-sourcetree

Folder A has some python code and java code. Folder A is a repo on bitbucket and source tree is being used to push commits to repo. The python side of it works fine.

I use eclipse to deal with the java code. I imported the java code from Folder A into eclipse workspace. All changes in Eclipse editor are reflected in the workspace project - but not the java folder in Folder A.

Is there someway I can make the eclipse edits show up in Folder A?

That way edits in my java workspace will show up in the commits to the repo.

Alternatively can I add the workspace project folder to my repo (without actually  moving it into my repo )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the solution is **Linked Folder**:

1. Create a empty java project
2. Open project properties. Select `Java Build Path` and click `Linked Source...`
3. Select `Folder A` for **Linked folder location**, click `Finish` to perform change.

The actual location of files under **Linked Folder** is under `Folder A`.

Another solution is create symbolic link under java project, set **target** to `Folder A`:

- For windows 7 or newer, execute command `mklink /J srcLink Folder_A`
- For unix, execute command `ln -s srcLink Folder_A`

After **srcLink** is created, remember to refresh project and add source folder.